# How to lock elbow rotation (forward kinematics)

Tags: rigging, armature, constraints

Before answering this question please consider that an 'answer' involving IK bone constraints should go in comments. In this question I am only interested in forward kinematics.

Many humanoid models use a T-pose like this:

[image: A fairly old fashioned T-pose]

I often end up doing custom rigs, and need to keep them simple (I really do). To avoid unrealistic bending of the elbow while animating, I want to constrain the rotation of the elbow joint.

One method (when using forward kinematics) is switch to Eulers and lock the rotation in UI, as illustrated by this picture:

[image]

However, some artists discourage the use of a straight T pose. So we often see this:

[image]

My guess is that an axis-angle rotation may do the trick in such cases, however figuring the rotation axis would require tedious calculations; also, behaviour when rotating an axis-angle-locked joint in 3D view is not very satisfying. Finally I don't really want to use something other than quaternion rotations if I can avoid it.

So, what would be a good way to constrain rotation in such cases?

Comment: Okay... I also want to ask about the same question with IK. But in such case rotation is locked via the bone panel (or is this method deprecated?) and I believe it would be adequate to file a separate question for this?

Comment: Yes this would be better to put into separate question

Comment: @Jerryno will the answer be different (testing this with IK now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use bone constraints to limit bones rotations (and other things) in pose mode:

Here is the wiki on [rotation limiting](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Constraints/Transform/Limit_Rotation).
The settings depend on actual bone setup and what the bone roll values are. Sometimes the bone roll needs to be also adjusted.

This will allow only rotation in local Z axis:

[image]

The range of motion can also be adjusted by setting the angle limits for appropriate axises.

Comment: Please add some more details on how to actually do it, an answer consisting of just a link isn't really an answer.

Comment: I think I tried this before; I don't know how to make it work for a non-straight T-pose. Have you tried?

Comment: Actually This seems to work when correctly configured. LimitX, LimitY set to zero or something small, Limit Z unchecked or set to something appropriate (assuming facing orientation on Z axis). Convert should be set to local space and For Transform should be checked. If you can edit your answer with appropriate info, or a screenshot, I will approve this answer.

Comment: Sure, I didn't know the actual setting, thanks.