# Eye Limit Rotation

Tags: rigging

I am having trouble with limiting the rotations for my eye lids. when my head is straight up and down the eye lids work perfectly but when I rotate the head the limit rotation on the eyes does not rotate with the head. I am at a loss for how to adjust this. Any help would be great! The first image is the head rotation but not the eye lid rotation. the other image shows the eye rig.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

After much googling I managed to find a thread that helped. I had tried limiting according to the Local Space but I didn't realize that I would have to adjust the values again and saw this as it not working. This link helped. and now I figured it out by re-adjusting the the values and just limiting the rotations.

[How to lock elbow rotation (forward kinematics)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/20912/how-to-lock-elbow-rotation-forward-kinematics)

[image]