# How to limit the rotation of knees, feet, ankles and similar joints?

Tags: animation, armature, bones, animation-nodes

Is there any trick to prevent bending of the knees, ankles and alike so they stop at a certain rotation point, let say 45 degree angle?
I have a character that I'd like the joints to stop rotating "naturally" so it doesn't look weird. The same goes for the knees, feet, ankles, arms, etc ...

See ref imgs and attached .blend file:
[image: screenshots]

.blend file is 37MB and maximum limit is 30MB on blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com so here's the link: http://we.tl/TFb1T7WNoV

No python scripts please. I'm a total noob.

Comment: There's a way to limit rotation on IK chains, and there's another to do it on FK chains. But I don't quite understand what your image is saying. The distance and position between the hips and the foot is very different between the two poses. I don't understand how you can expect the right bending on the left pose.

Comment: @AntonioBuch For human bones it's impossible to bend it after a certain point. Let's say the knee can't bend backwards cus it would break. The same thing goes for the elbow, fingers and etc. I'd like my characters fingers to behave like human bones. So in real life, if my finger bones bend too much the wrong way they would break and I have to go to the hospital ;)

Comment: The common approach to this is that the animator don't push the rig so much. Not pretty fancy actually, but it's the usual behavior. For instance, you can see plenty of animations with the fingers waaaaay rotated on the opposite direction. In this case, it helps with the pose appeal. For me, limiting is a disadvantage.

Comment: @AntonioBuch In the ref img the ankles are bent in an abnormal way since the foot is placed on the ground and the knees touching the ground at the same time. In real life that's not possible, right?

Comment: BTW was that rig made with Blenrig?

Comment: @AntonioBuch Yes. I got it yesterday, documentation included. 
BlenRig 5 by Juan Pablo Bouza. Tutorial on YT soon.

Comment: As an animator, you probably just rotate the feet's ball control to correct that. As a rigger, you are requesting for an automated way to do that. So the feet bend to prevent that ankle bending. It sounds very very complex.

Comment: @AntonioBuch Not 100% sure what you mean by that. 
I thought maybe it was possible to constrain something from rotating but I'm probably wrong. So I'm thinking out loud guessing it's not possible to do what I've asked for. But I appreciate your effort and thank you for your help.

Comment: For joints like the fingers you can use the Limit Rotation constraint, covered in this question: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/20912/how-to-lock-elbow-rotation-forward-kinematics/20936#20936

Comment: For IK chains like the knee (or sometimes the elbow) you can limit the rotation in the Bone's properties like you can see here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32697/can-ik-constraint-be-setup-so-it-respects-constraints-of-affected-bones Note that this only applies for the leg and not to the ankle.

Comment: And, finally, for your main question: it could be possible but it would be very difficult. What you need here is a system that controls the distance between the hips and the ankle, and: a) prevents the hips to down further than a given distance and/or b) bends the feet to keep the ankle relaxed enough. 
That said, I couldn't figure out how to do that in my own rigs, no way to do that on a Blenrig one!  At least we focused the question in the right direction. My bet is: don't do it, let the animator control that ;) Good luck!

Comment: @AntonioBuch It worked! Thank you so much for your help. Much appreciated, sir.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**
In looked back at this old answer and realized you were using an IK rig. To limit this, there is an inverse kinematics section to the bone properties.

Select the bone you want to constrain, and make sure you are in posed mode. There should be a bone constraints window:

[image]

By check boxing 'limit' you can set a bone to only bend so far in IK mode.

**_________________________**

```
  Old Answer
```

[image]

You can add a "limit Rotation" constraint, as you can see set up there. 
It also has other bone limitations; go ahead and mess around with it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% as I've not used this in the more recent versions of blender, but I believe that in the "properties" window, under "bone costraints", if you "add bone constraint2 and select the type "transformation", you can input the bones max and min x,y, and z rotation.

I hope that helps.

Comment: I've tried your solution and it doesn't seem to work. Or your explanation is not sufficient enough for me to understand. Please open the .blend file and be a 100% sure in your answer.

Comment: Looking at your image, your rig looks a lot lot more complex than the simple armatures I have used, so it might be that my answer was incorrect or not helpful enough. I apologize that I could not help more, I am only an amateur myself.